# How do I use 'sed' to modify a file with the output of another file from a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I am currently working on a bash script for my own amusement and for creeping out my friends, which is basically just an ssmtp command with a countdown in a loop.

```
while true; do
echo "sending..."
sudo ssmtp user@domain.com -v < /home/apx/Desktop/email.txt
echo "mail sent." 
date +"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S $HOSTNAME"
echo "wait for cooldown..."
timecount(){
    min=0
    sec=5
    while [ $min -ge 0 ]; do
            while [ $sec -ge 0 ]; do
                    echo -ne "0$min:$sec\033[0K\r"
                    sec=$((sec-1))
                    sleep 1
            done
            sec=59
            min=$((min-1))
    done
}
timecount
done
```

I would like to learn a way to use cat or something to print the first line of a text file containing a list of email addresses and then pipe the output into sed which would edit /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf to use a different authuser with the same authpass, send an email, countdown, and repeat with the next email address on the list until it must start from the top again.

/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf

```
root=postmaster
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
UseSTARTTLS=YES
AuthUser=user@domain.com
AuthPass=password
#rewriteDomain=
hostname=apx
#FromLineOverride=YES
```

sed to edit authuser value with input from list text file > send email > countdown > repeat with next address in line

I have a basic understanding of sed but not enough to accomplish this task. I realize that I've likely made this more complicated than it has to be, but.... any help understanding this better would be much appreciated.

Comment: how could i get variable $p to function as the replacement text, or is that even possible? `echo $p | sudo sed -i '/AuthUser/s/= .*/= $p/' /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`

Answer (score 0):

sorry for being late reply .. ok now it works well now you can send from many emails to one email plz follow these steps :

1. first you need to go and allow less secure apps for all emails which
   found in `emailad.txt` go this link on gmail then `turn on` 
   https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
2. go to any directory for example /home/apx/Desktop then create new folder for example `folder` this folder should contains:

   ```
   `ssmtp.conf`(Note: ssmtp.conf found in `/etc/ssmtp/` directory), `email.txt`(message), `emailad.txt`(emails) then start type this script:
   ```

`#!/bin/bash`

Number of Emails in `y` variable

`y=3`

Number of Messages for each email :

```
echo "No. Of Msgs For each Email :";read number_of_messages;
```

loops for our emails

```
for (( x=1; x<=y; x++ ));
do
```

fetch emails which found in `emailad.txt` file

```
emails=`echo $( cat emailad.txt | sed -n ''$x''p )`
print_emails=`echo "$emails"`
```

search for any email address inside ssmtp.conf.bak file with `smtp` variable

```
smtp=`grep -E -o "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b" /home/apx/Desktop/folder/ssmtp.conf.bak`
```

then concatenate `ssmtp.conf.bak` file with `sed` to search for any email address inside `ssmtp.conf.bak` then replace it with our emails which found in emailad.txt file

```
cat /home/apx/Desktop/folder/ssmtp.conf.bak | sed 's/'$smtp'/'$print_emails'/g'  /home/apx/Desktop/folder/ssmtp.conf.bak > /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf



for (( f=1; f<=number_of_messages; f++ ));
do
ssmtp user@domain.com < email.txt    //email.txt which containes the message
sleep 5
done
done&
```

full script:

```
echo "No. Of Msgs For each Email :";read number_of_messages;
y=3
for (( x=1; x<=y; x++ ));
do
emails=`echo $( cat emailad.txt | sed -n ''$x''p )`
print_emails=`echo "$emails"`
smtp=`grep -E -o "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b" ssmtp.conf.bak`
cat ssmtp.conf.bak | sed 's/'$smtp'/'$print_emails'/g'  ssmtp.conf.bak > /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
for (( f=1; f<=number_of_messages; f++ ));
do
ssmtp user@domain.com < emails.txt
sleep 5
done
done&`
```

Comment: i greatly appreciate your input, thank you. i tried exactly as you instructed. i added `ssmtp user@domain.com -v < /home/apx/Desktop/email.txt` right before the sleep function. when running, it manages to loop and it will send an email, sleep, but it refuses to change the email address. ive gone over your code and i simply do not understand where it goes wrong. it should work, should it not? im able to sed ssmtp.comf from the terminal no problem.

Comment: i edited it please check again the script , feedback me please !

Comment: it didnt make it this far, but it looks like the ssmtp command will try to make each email address send a message to itself. in my mind what i would like to happen is a list of email addresses sending an email to a single address. i have two files, email.txt which contains the message, and emailad.txt which contains the addresses. this is what i have tried.

Comment: i tried to format this to be prettier but i failed. anyway, this is the code that i am running 

#!/bin/bash

y=4
for (( x=1; x<=y; x++ ));
do
emails=`echo  $( cat /home/apx/Desktop/emailad.txt | sed -n ''$x''p )`
print_emails=`echo "$emails"`
smtp=`grep -E -o "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b" /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`
cat /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf | sed -e 's/'$smtp'/'$print_emails'/g' > /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf.bak 
sleep 10
email_file_path="/home/apx/Desktop/emailad.txt"
while true;
do
if [ -f $email_file_path ];
then
ssmtp $print_emails -v
break
fi
sleep 5
done
done

Comment: sorry being late now check my answer again it works fine now !

Comment: it didnt work man. but i did manage to get my issue solved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633341/how-can-i-increment-one-line-at-a-time-from-a-text-file-and-sed-the-output-to-an#comment49672998_30636407