# How can I increment one line at a time from a text file and sed the output to another file?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a text file containing, e.g.:

```
user0@domain.com
user1@domain.com
user2@domain.com
user3@domain.com
```

and ssmtp.conf containing:

```
AuthUser=user0@domain.com
```

How can I take the first line and `sed` ssmtp.conf to end up with this:

```
AuthUser=user1@domain.com
```

I need it to sleep for a few seconds and then change to

```
AuthUser=user2@domain.com
```

and so forth. Currently, with the help of a couple users here this is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
y=4 
for (( x=1; x<=y; x++ )); do
emails=`echo  $( cat /home/apx/Desktop/emailaddresses.txt | sed -n ''$x''p )`
sed -i "/AuthUser/s/= .*/= $emails/" /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
ssmtp blahh@blahh.com -v < /home/apx/Desktop/message.txt
sleep 1
done
```

When I run this, it cycles through 4 times. Each time it sends an email, it sends all 4 from user0@domain.com rather than user0, then user1, then user2, and then user3, which is what I've been struggling to achieve. I just realized that its not changing at all. It just stays the way I left it last. I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Create a template `ssmtp.conf` file, so that `AuthUser=%%EMAIL%%`.  Then, replace using the template file like `sed "s/%%EMAIL%%/$email" < ssmtp.template.conf > ssmtp.conf; sleep 5`.  Loop.

Comment: i created a template named `ssmtp.template.conf` containing `AuthUser=%%EMAIL%%`. then, i used `sed "s/%%EMAIL%%/$emails" < /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.template.conf > /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf;` and it caused all the information in ssmtp.conf to be erased.  (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Comment: Yep, expected. The template file should be a copy of the original ssmtp.conf file, just with the AuthUser line changed.

Comment: ahh okay that makes sense, one sec lemme try that

Comment: hmm. ssmtp.conf is still being erased. before i run the script, the template is identical to the original with the exception of `AuthUser=%%EMAIL%%`

Comment: here is a screenshot of the script, i didnt want to type it in a comment because formatting it correctly is a pain https://i.imgur.com/Bj4Ix9m.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
while read -r addr; do
    sudo m4 -Daddr="$addr" >/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf <<<'AuthUser=addr'
    sudo ssmtp blahh@blahh.com -v </home/apx/Desktop/message.txt
    sleep 1
done </home/apx/Desktop/emailaddresses.txt
```

Comment: this worked! i like that this is simple. at first it was erasing the whole file and only leaving one line, so i just added what else i wanted to appear around the authuser=addr and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

AddressSources=/home/apx/Desktop/emailaddresses.txt

# number of email
y=$( grep -c -e "${AddressSources}" )

# loop (from last to first email)
while [ ${y} -gt 0 ]
 do
   # catch the specific mail using the line number
   email="$( sed "${y} !d" "${AddressSources}" )"

   # adapt the ssmtp.conf
   sed -i "s/^\(AuthUser=\).*/\1${email}/" /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf

   # send the message
   ssmtp blahh@blahh.com -v < /home/apx/Desktop/message.txt

   # wait and cycle to next email
   sleep 1
   let y-=1
done
```

- based on your script
- there is a space character in your code but not in the data sample, i take the data reference
- loop from the end to avoid the extra varaible but just a choice
- you could use a `while read` instead of a sed to take line by line and loop through email

Answer (score 0):

im using gmail smtp server and if you try to allow smtp on gmail you should allow secure apps on this link you should `turn on`
 https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

**Execute this script as a root user**

```
cp -avr /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf . > /dev/null
echo "No. Of Msgs For each Email :";read number_of_messages;
echo "Destination Email: ";read Email
y=3
for (( x=1; x<=y; x++ ));
do
emails=`echo $( cat emails | sed -n ''$x''p )`
print_emails=`echo "$emails"`
smtp=`grep -E -o "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b" ssmtp.conf.bak`

cat ssmtp.conf | sed 's/'$smtp'/'$print_emails'/g'  ssmtp.conf > /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
for (( f=1; f<=number_of_messages; f++ ));
do
ssmtp $Email < msg
sleep 5
done
done&
```

tested and works perfectly

**first i have typed 4 to send 4 messages for each email** (checkmeoffon@gmail.com, checkmeonoff@gmail.com)
[image]

**Next checkmeoffon@gmail.com 4 messages**
[image]

**Next checkmeonoff@gmail.com 4 messages**
[image]